# Materialize initialize all items with class

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

I am trying to use the JavaScript library of MaterializeCSS to initialize a few `tooltips`. I would like to give them all the same CSS class (`.tooltip`) which would thus initialise each element containing that class at once instead of giving them separate classes and initialising them one by one.
My current code:

```
<i class="material-icons tooltip1" data-position="bottom" data-tooltip="Add image">attach_file</i>
<i class="material-icons tooltip2" data-position="bottom" data-tooltip="Edit">edit</i>
```

My JS:

```
var elem1 = document.querySelector('.tooltip1');
var instance1 = M.Tooltip.init(elem1);
var elem2 = document.querySelector('.tooltip2');
var instance2 = M.Tooltip.init(elem2);
```

I have googled and stackoverflowed but it was to no avail as I only found ways of initialising them one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

> [.querySelectorAll(selectors)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll): returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

The snippet:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip').forEach(function(ele, idx) {
    M.Tooltip.init(ele);
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<i class="material-icons tooltip" data-position="bottom" data-tooltip="Add image">attach_file</i>
<i class="material-icons tooltip" data-position="bottom" data-tooltip="Edit">edit</i>
```